# SSRS: Collect Small Slices on a Pie Chart

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-grouping

What i want is the behaviour described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207043.aspx).
Basically i want to group small slices into a larger one. My problem is that the link does this based on what percentage the slices represent in the pie; I want to do this based in values of the series.
In the image below [image: this]

I want to show all BizDevs as just one bizdev. can any one point me ot the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to group certain categories together, you need to group on an expression that does this and not the base field.

Say I have simplified data like:

[image]

Which gives a chart as you'd expect:

[image]

In the category group we need to update the **Group on** value and the **Label** value:

[image]

Set the expression to:

```
=IIf(Fields!MyGroup.Value Like "BizDev*", "BizDev", Fields!MyGroup.Value)
```

i.e. if the group name starts with *BizDev*, put these in the same group.

These will now be grouped together:

[image]